# Text Alignment in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

```js
    
        var data = 
        [{"seq":"1","start":"Account","end":"Order","relation":"Account","rows":"1"},
        {"seq":"2","start":"Account","end":"Attachment","relation":"Parent","rows":"10"}
        ,{"seq":"3","start":"Order","end":"Account","relation":"Account","rows":"15"}
        ,{"seq":"4","start":"Attachment","end":"Account","relation":"Parent","rows":"55"}
        ,{"seq":"5","start":"Attachment","end":"Campaign","relation":"Parent","rows":"45"}
        ,{"seq":"6","start":"Attachment","end":"Lead","relation":"Parent","rows":"47"}
        ,{"seq":"7","start":"Lead","end":"Attachment","relation":"Parent","rows":"75"}
        ,{"seq":"8","start":"Campaign","end":"Attachment","relation":"Parent","rows":"34"},
        {"seq":"9","start":"Order","end":"Account","relation":"Account","rows":"99"}
        ,{"seq":"10","start":"Attachment","end":"Account","relation":"Parent","rows":"12"}
        ,{"seq":"11","start":"Attachment","end":"Campaign","relation":"Parent","rows":"5"}
        ,{"seq":"12","start":"Attachment","end":"Lead","relation":"Parent","rows":"75"}]; 

 var ellipseSelected, pathSelected, parentNodeX, parentNodeY, relationshipName, indexEdge, fromData, toData, nodeSelected, startNodeSelected;
 //flag =1 ,when we have both src and trg
 var flag = 1;
 var newCount = 0;
 var edges = d3.selectAll('.edge');
 var path = d3.selectAll('.path')
 var allEllipse = d3.selectAll('ellipse');
 var allNodes = d3.selectAll('.node');
 var theGraph = document.getElementById('graph0') //getContainer
 var polygon = document.getElementsByTagName('polygon')[0] //getPolygon to insert after

 var allEdgesJS = document.getElementsByClassName("edge"); //select all Edges
 for (var i = 0; i < allEdgesJS.length; i++) { //Loop through edges to move
   theGraph.insertBefore(allEdgesJS[i], polygon.nextSibling); //insert after polygon

 }

 function ellipseAdd() {

   d3.select(ellipseSelected.parentNode)
     .append("circle")
     .attr('cx', parentNodeX) //thisParentBBox.left + thisParentBBox.width/2)
     .attr('cy', parentNodeY)
     .attr("r", 10)
     .attr("stroke-width", 1)
     .attr("stroke", "white")
     .style('fill', '#CE2029');
   d3.select(ellipseSelected.parentNode)
     .data([toData])
     .append("text")
     .attr('x', parentNodeX - 8)
     .attr('y', parentNodeY + 4).text(0).style('fill', 'white')
     .attr("font-size", "8px")
     .transition()
     .duration(3000)
     .tween("text", function(d) {
       var i = d3.interpolate(fromData, d),
         prec = (d + "").split("."),
         round = (prec.length > 1) ? Math.pow(10, prec[1].length) : 1;
       return function(t) {
         this.textContent = Math.round(i(t) * round) / round;
       };
     });

 }

 function blinker() {
   if (flag == 0) {
     //for adding ellipse and text to it
     ellipseAdd();

   } else {
     //blink 3 things\
     //ellipse
     ellipseAdd();


     d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[indexEdge].id + ' path').style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 1)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 1)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 1)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').style('stroke-width', 1).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', "#ff800e").style('stroke-width', 1); //select current id from array //select current id from array

     d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[indexEdge].id + ' polygon')
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', '#CE2029').style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 2)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', '#CE2029').style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 2)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('fill', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 2)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').style('fill', 'grey').style('stroke-width', 1).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', "#ff800e").style('fill', "#ff800e").style('stroke-width', 1); //select current id from array


     d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[indexEdge].id + ' text').style('opacity', 0)
       .transition().style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', '#CE2029')
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', '#CE2029')
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', '#CE2029').style('fill', '#CE2029')
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', "#ff800e");

   }
 }

 edges.style('opacity', 1);
 allNodes.style('fill', "white");
 path.style('fill', "yellow");
 var indexAndEdge = [];
 var countOnNode = [];
 edges.each(function(d, i) {
   var thisEdgeCount = this.id.substring(4);
   debugger
   indexAndEdge.push({ //push index you are at, the edge count worked out above and the id
     index: i,
     count: thisEdgeCount,
     id: this.id,
     start: String(this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue).split("->")[0],
     destination: String(this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue).split("->")[1],
     relation: this.childNodes[6].childNodes[0]

   })
   d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[i].id + ' polygon').style('fill', 'grey').style('stroke', 'grey');
   d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[i].id + ' path').style('stroke', 'grey');

 });

 d3.selectAll('.node').each(function(d, i) {
   var thisNodeCount = this.id;
   debugger
   countOnNode.push({ //push index you are at, the edge count worked out above and the id
     id: thisNodeCount,
     prevData: 0,
     incrementData: 0,
     title: this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
     name: String(this.childNodes[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue)

   })
 });

 function timer() {
   setTimeout(function(d) {

     if (newCount < data.length) { //if we havent gone through all edges

       if (data[newCount].end.length == 0) {
         flag = 0;
         for (j = 0; j < allNodes[0].length; j++) {
           //if sourseName matches    
           if (String(allNodes[0][j].childNodes[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue) == data[newCount].start) {
             ellipseSelected = d3.selectAll('.node')[0][j].childNodes[2];

             parentNodeX = ellipseSelected.attributes.cx.value - ellipseSelected.attributes.rx.value + (2 * ellipseSelected.attributes.rx.value);
             parentNodeY = ellipseSelected.attributes.cy.value - (ellipseSelected.attributes.ry.value / 2);
             //send the data to interpolate
             //match id and update prevData ,incrementData 
             for (var l = 0; l < countOnNode.length; l++) {
               if (countOnNode[l].id == d3.selectAll('.node')[0][j].id) {
                 countOnNode[l].prevData = countOnNode[l].incrementData;
                 countOnNode[l].incrementData = data[newCount].rows;
                 fromData = countOnNode[l].prevData;
                 toData = countOnNode[l].incrementData;
               }
             }

             blinker();
             flag = 1;
             if (flag == 1) {
               break;
             }


           }
         }


       } else {
         //check relation and targetNode
         //check target
         flag = 1;
         for (var j = 0; j < allNodes[0].length; j++) {
           if (String(allNodes[0][j].childNodes[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue) == data[newCount].end) {
             ellipseSelected = d3.selectAll('.node')[0][j].childNodes[2];
             parentNodeX = ellipseSelected.attributes.cx.value - ellipseSelected.attributes.rx.value + (2 * ellipseSelected.attributes.rx.value);
             parentNodeY = ellipseSelected.attributes.cy.value - (ellipseSelected.attributes.ry.value / 2);

             for (var l = 0; l < countOnNode.length; l++) {

               if (countOnNode[l].id == d3.selectAll('.node')[0][j].id) {

                 countOnNode[l].prevData = countOnNode[l].incrementData;

                 countOnNode[l].incrementData = +data[newCount].rows + +countOnNode[l].prevData;
                 fromData = countOnNode[l].prevData;
                 toData = countOnNode[l].incrementData;
                 nodeSelected = l;
                 // console.log(" j =" + j + "l "+l+ " fromData  " + fromData + " toData  "+toData);
               }
             }
             debugger
             for (var ll = 0; ll < countOnNode.length; ll++) {

               if (countOnNode[ll].name == data[newCount].start) {
                 debugger;
                 //  console.log(data[newCount]);
                 startNodeSelected = ll;

               }
             }

             debugger
             //set the edge by checking relation
             for (var k = 0; k < indexAndEdge.length; k++) {

               //if(edges[0][k].childNodes[7].childNodes[0] == indexAndEdge)
               if ((data[newCount].relation.trim() == (String(indexAndEdge[k].relation.nodeValue).trim()) &&
                   (((countOnNode[nodeSelected].title == indexAndEdge[k].destination) && (countOnNode[startNodeSelected].title == indexAndEdge[k].start)) || ((countOnNode[nodeSelected].title == indexAndEdge[k].start) && (countOnNode[startNodeSelected].title == indexAndEdge[k].destination))))) {
                 indexEdge = k;
               }
             }
             blinker();
             flag = 0;
             if (flag == 0) {
               break;
             }

           }
         }

       }


       //allEllipse 

       newCount++;
       timer();
     } else {
       // count =0 ;
       timer()
       console.log('end') //end
     }
   }, 3000)
 }


 timer();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
 -->
<!-- Title: graphname Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="308pt" height="131pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 308.09 131.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 127)">
<title>graphname</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-127 304.095,-127 304.095,4 -4,4"/>
<!-- 0 -->
<g id="node1" class="node"><title>0</title>
<ellipse fill="#b2dfee" stroke="#b2dfee" cx="51.4971" cy="-105" rx="42.4939" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="51.4971" y="-101.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Account</text>
</g>
<!-- 1 -->
<g id="node2" class="node"><title>1</title>
<ellipse fill="#b2dfee" stroke="#b2dfee" cx="177.497" cy="-18" rx="51.9908" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="177.497" y="-14.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Attachment</text>
</g>
<!-- 0&#45;&gt;1 -->
<g id="edge1" class="edge"><title>0&#45;&gt;1</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#cd0000" d="M81.6636,-83.6496C104.156,-68.4764 134.397,-48.0758 154.846,-34.2806"/>
<polygon fill="#cd0000" stroke="#cd0000" points="79.4899,-80.894 73.1573,-89.388 83.4047,-86.697 79.4899,-80.894"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="143.997" y="-57.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00"> Parent </text>
</g>
<!-- 2 -->
<g id="node3" class="node"><title>2</title>
<ellipse fill="#b2dfee" stroke="#b2dfee" cx="32.4971" cy="-18" rx="32.4942" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="32.4971" y="-14.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Order</text>
</g>
<!-- 0&#45;&gt;2 -->
<g id="edge2" class="edge"><title>0&#45;&gt;2</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#cd0000" d="M36.6269,-78.2339C35.365,-75.1966 34.2755,-72.0805 33.4971,-69 30.8171,-58.3937 30.5329,-46.1155 30.9355,-36.3806"/>
<polygon fill="#cd0000" stroke="#cd0000" points="33.6008,-80.0185 41.0756,-87.527 39.9146,-76.9959 33.6008,-80.0185"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="61.4971" y="-57.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00"> Account </text>
</g>
<!-- 3 -->
<g id="node4" class="node"><title>3</title>
<ellipse fill="#b2dfee" stroke="#b2dfee" cx="177.497" cy="-105" rx="47.3916" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="177.497" y="-101.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Campaign</text>
</g>
<!-- 3&#45;&gt;1 -->
<g id="edge3" class="edge"><title>3&#45;&gt;1</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#cd0000" d="M177.497,-76.7339C177.497,-63.4194 177.497,-47.806 177.497,-36.1754"/>
<polygon fill="#cd0000" stroke="#cd0000" points="173.997,-76.7989 177.497,-86.799 180.997,-76.799 173.997,-76.7989"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="198.997" y="-57.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00"> Parent </text>
</g>
<!-- 4 -->
<g id="node5" class="node"><title>4</title>
<ellipse fill="#b2dfee" stroke="#b2dfee" cx="271.497" cy="-105" rx="28.6953" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="271.497" y="-101.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Lead</text>
</g>
<!-- 4&#45;&gt;1 -->
<g id="edge4" class="edge"><title>4&#45;&gt;1</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#cd0000" d="M251.874,-81.4584C243.735,-72.5603 233.988,-62.4628 224.497,-54 216.904,-47.2291 208.071,-40.4074 200.126,-34.6078"/>
<polygon fill="#cd0000" stroke="#cd0000" points="249.277,-83.8042 258.567,-88.8979 254.481,-79.1226 249.277,-83.8042"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="259.997" y="-57.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00"> Parent </text>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here,circle is added to .svg file.And then text to that circle is added. I want to add text at centre of circle and also if number is bigger like 10000 ,it should fit to that circle.

I tried with
 .attr('height', 'auto')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')

But,as position of text is decided on which node is added(present in .svg file) and not on circle position,it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Create SVG groups to hold the circles and text labels. Adjust the position of both circles and text using transform attribute of group elements. Set text-anchor attribute of text element as middle.

```
var circles = d3.select(ellipseSelected.parentNode)
     .append("g")   
     .attr("transform","translate("+parentNodeX+","+parentNodeY+")")

circles.append("circle")    
     .attr("r", 10)
     .attr("stroke-width", 1)
     .attr("stroke", "white")
     .style('fill', '#CE2029');

d3.select(ellipseSelected.parentNode)
     .data([toData]);

circles.data([toData]).append("text")
     .style("dominant-baseline","central")
     .attr("dx", 0)     
     .attr('text-anchor',"middle")   
     .attr("font-size", "8px")
     .transition()
     .duration(3000)
     .tween("text", function(d) {
       var i = d3.interpolate(fromData, d),
         prec = (d + "").split("."),
         round = (prec.length > 1) ? Math.pow(10, prec[1].length) : 1;
       return function(t) {         
         this.textContent = Math.round(i(t) * round) / round;        
         //Update node radius based on text length.      
         var rad = this.textContent.length>3?(this.textContent.length/3)*10:10;
         d3.select(this.parentNode).select("circle").attr("r",rad);
       };
     });
```

```js
var data = 
        [{"seq":"1","start":"Account","end":"Order","relation":"Account","rows":"1"},
        {"seq":"2","start":"Account","end":"Attachment","relation":"Parent","rows":"10"}
        ,{"seq":"3","start":"Order","end":"Account","relation":"Account","rows":"15"}
        ,{"seq":"4","start":"Attachment","end":"Account","relation":"Parent","rows":"55"}
        ,{"seq":"5","start":"Attachment","end":"Campaign","relation":"Parent","rows":"45"}
        ,{"seq":"6","start":"Attachment","end":"Lead","relation":"Parent","rows":"47"}
        ,{"seq":"7","start":"Lead","end":"Attachment","relation":"Parent","rows":"75"}
        ,{"seq":"8","start":"Campaign","end":"Attachment","relation":"Parent","rows":"34"},
        {"seq":"9","start":"Order","end":"Account","relation":"Account","rows":"99"}
        ,{"seq":"10","start":"Attachment","end":"Account","relation":"Parent","rows":"12"}
        ,{"seq":"11","start":"Attachment","end":"Campaign","relation":"Parent","rows":"5"}
        ,{"seq":"12","start":"Attachment","end":"Lead","relation":"Parent","rows":"75"}]; 

 var ellipseSelected, pathSelected, parentNodeX, parentNodeY, relationshipName, indexEdge, fromData, toData, nodeSelected, startNodeSelected;
 //flag =1 ,when we have both src and trg
 var flag = 1;
 var newCount = 0;
 var edges = d3.selectAll('.edge');
 var path = d3.selectAll('.path')
 var allEllipse = d3.selectAll('ellipse');
 var allNodes = d3.selectAll('.node');
 var theGraph = document.getElementById('graph0') //getContainer
 var polygon = document.getElementsByTagName('polygon')[0] //getPolygon to insert after

 var allEdgesJS = document.getElementsByClassName("edge"); //select all Edges
 for (var i = 0; i < allEdgesJS.length; i++) { //Loop through edges to move
   theGraph.insertBefore(allEdgesJS[i], polygon.nextSibling); //insert after polygon

 }

 function ellipseAdd() {

   var circles = d3.select(ellipseSelected.parentNode)
     .append("g")   
     .attr("transform","translate("+parentNodeX+","+parentNodeY+")")
   
   circles.append("circle")    
     .attr("r", 10)
     .attr("stroke-width", 1)
     .attr("stroke", "white")
     .style('fill', '#CE2029');
   
   d3.select(ellipseSelected.parentNode)
     .data([toData]);
   
   circles.data([toData]).append("text")
     .style("dominant-baseline","central")
     .attr("dx", 0)     
     .attr('text-anchor',"middle")   
     .attr("font-size", "8px")
     .transition()
     .duration(3000)
     .tween("text", function(d) {
       var i = d3.interpolate(fromData, d),
         prec = (d + "").split("."),
         round = (prec.length > 1) ? Math.pow(10, prec[1].length) : 1;
       return function(t) {         
         this.textContent = Math.round(i(t) * round) / round;        
         var rad = this.textContent.length>3?(this.textContent.length/3)*10:10;
         d3.select(this.parentNode).select("circle").attr("r",rad);
       };
     });

 }

 function blinker() {
   if (flag == 0) {
     //for adding ellipse and text to it
     ellipseAdd();

   } else {
     //blink 3 things\
     //ellipse
     ellipseAdd();


     d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[indexEdge].id + ' path').style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 1)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 1)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 1)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').style('stroke-width', 1).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', "#ff800e").style('stroke-width', 1); //select current id from array //select current id from array

     d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[indexEdge].id + ' polygon')
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', '#CE2029').style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 2)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', '#CE2029').style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 2)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', '#CE2029').style('fill', '#CE2029').style('stroke-width', 2)
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', 'grey').style('fill', 'grey').style('stroke-width', 1).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('stroke', "#ff800e").style('fill', "#ff800e").style('stroke-width', 1); //select current id from array


     d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[indexEdge].id + ' text').style('opacity', 0)
       .transition().style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', '#CE2029')
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', '#CE2029')
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', '#CE2029').style('fill', '#CE2029')
       .transition().duration(300).duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', 'grey').duration(300).style('opacity', 1)
       .transition().style('fill', "#ff800e");

   }
 }

 edges.style('opacity', 1);
 allNodes.style('fill', "white");
 path.style('fill', "yellow");
 var indexAndEdge = [];
 var countOnNode = [];
 edges.each(function(d, i) {
   var thisEdgeCount = this.id.substring(4);
   debugger
   indexAndEdge.push({ //push index you are at, the edge count worked out above and the id
     index: i,
     count: thisEdgeCount,
     id: this.id,
     start: String(this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue).split("->")[0],
     destination: String(this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue).split("->")[1],
     relation: this.childNodes[6].childNodes[0]

   })
   d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[i].id + ' polygon').style('fill', 'grey').style('stroke', 'grey');
   d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[i].id + ' path').style('stroke', 'grey');

 });

 d3.selectAll('.node').each(function(d, i) {
   var thisNodeCount = this.id;
   debugger
   countOnNode.push({ //push index you are at, the edge count worked out above and the id
     id: thisNodeCount,
     prevData: 0,
     incrementData: 0,
     title: this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
     name: String(this.childNodes[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue)

   })
 });

 function timer() {
   setTimeout(function(d) {

     if (newCount < data.length) { //if we havent gone through all edges

       if (data[newCount].end.length == 0) {
         flag = 0;
         for (j = 0; j < allNodes[0].length; j++) {
           //if sourseName matches    
           if (String(allNodes[0][j].childNodes[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue) == data[newCount].start) {
             ellipseSelected = d3.selectAll('.node')[0][j].childNodes[2];

             parentNodeX = ellipseSelected.attributes.cx.value - ellipseSelected.attributes.rx.value + (2 * ellipseSelected.attributes.rx.value);
             parentNodeY = ellipseSelected.attributes.cy.value - (ellipseSelected.attributes.ry.value / 2);
             //send the data to interpolate
             //match id and update prevData ,incrementData 
             for (var l = 0; l < countOnNode.length; l++) {
               if (countOnNode[l].id == d3.selectAll('.node')[0][j].id) {
                 countOnNode[l].prevData = countOnNode[l].incrementData;
                 countOnNode[l].incrementData = data[newCount].rows;
                 fromData = countOnNode[l].prevData;
                 toData = countOnNode[l].incrementData;
               }
             }

             blinker();
             flag = 1;
             if (flag == 1) {
               break;
             }


           }
         }


       } else {
         //check relation and targetNode
         //check target
         flag = 1;
         for (var j = 0; j < allNodes[0].length; j++) {
           if (String(allNodes[0][j].childNodes[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue) == data[newCount].end) {
             ellipseSelected = d3.selectAll('.node')[0][j].childNodes[2];
             parentNodeX = ellipseSelected.attributes.cx.value - ellipseSelected.attributes.rx.value + (2 * ellipseSelected.attributes.rx.value);
             parentNodeY = ellipseSelected.attributes.cy.value - (ellipseSelected.attributes.ry.value / 2);

             for (var l = 0; l < countOnNode.length; l++) {

               if (countOnNode[l].id == d3.selectAll('.node')[0][j].id) {

                 countOnNode[l].prevData = countOnNode[l].incrementData;

                 countOnNode[l].incrementData = +data[newCount].rows + +countOnNode[l].prevData;
                 fromData = countOnNode[l].prevData;
                 toData = countOnNode[l].incrementData;
                 nodeSelected = l;
                 // console.log(" j =" + j + "l "+l+ " fromData  " + fromData + " toData  "+toData);
               }
             }
             debugger
             for (var ll = 0; ll < countOnNode.length; ll++) {

               if (countOnNode[ll].name == data[newCount].start) {
                 debugger;
                 //  console.log(data[newCount]);
                 startNodeSelected = ll;

               }
             }

             debugger
             //set the edge by checking relation
             for (var k = 0; k < indexAndEdge.length; k++) {

               //if(edges[0][k].childNodes[7].childNodes[0] == indexAndEdge)
               if ((data[newCount].relation.trim() == (String(indexAndEdge[k].relation.nodeValue).trim()) &&
                   (((countOnNode[nodeSelected].title == indexAndEdge[k].destination) && (countOnNode[startNodeSelected].title == indexAndEdge[k].start)) || ((countOnNode[nodeSelected].title == indexAndEdge[k].start) && (countOnNode[startNodeSelected].title == indexAndEdge[k].destination))))) {
                 indexEdge = k;
               }
             }
             blinker();
             flag = 0;
             if (flag == 0) {
               break;
             }

           }
         }

       }


       //allEllipse 

       newCount++;
       timer();
     } else {
       // count =0 ;
       timer()
  //     console.log('end') //end
     }
   }, 3000)
 }


 timer();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
 -->
<!-- Title: graphname Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="308pt" height="131pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 308.09 131.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 127)">
<title>graphname</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-127 304.095,-127 304.095,4 -4,4"/>
<!-- 0 -->
<g id="node1" class="node"><title>0</title>
<ellipse fill="#b2dfee" stroke="#b2dfee" cx="51.4971" cy="-105" rx="42.4939" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="51.4971" y="-101.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Account</text>
</g>
<!-- 1 -->
<g id="node2" class="node"><title>1</title>
<ellipse fill="#b2dfee" stroke="#b2dfee" cx="177.497" cy="-18" rx="51.9908" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="177.497" y="-14.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Attachment</text>
</g>
<!-- 0&#45;&gt;1 -->
<g id="edge1" class="edge"><title>0&#45;&gt;1</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#cd0000" d="M81.6636,-83.6496C104.156,-68.4764 134.397,-48.0758 154.846,-34.2806"/>
<polygon fill="#cd0000" stroke="#cd0000" points="79.4899,-80.894 73.1573,-89.388 83.4047,-86.697 79.4899,-80.894"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="143.997" y="-57.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00"> Parent </text>
</g>
<!-- 2 -->
<g id="node3" class="node"><title>2</title>
<ellipse fill="#b2dfee" stroke="#b2dfee" cx="32.4971" cy="-18" rx="32.4942" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="32.4971" y="-14.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Order</text>
</g>
<!-- 0&#45;&gt;2 -->
<g id="edge2" class="edge"><title>0&#45;&gt;2</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#cd0000" d="M36.6269,-78.2339C35.365,-75.1966 34.2755,-72.0805 33.4971,-69 30.8171,-58.3937 30.5329,-46.1155 30.9355,-36.3806"/>
<polygon fill="#cd0000" stroke="#cd0000" points="33.6008,-80.0185 41.0756,-87.527 39.9146,-76.9959 33.6008,-80.0185"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="61.4971" y="-57.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00"> Account </text>
</g>
<!-- 3 -->
<g id="node4" class="node"><title>3</title>
<ellipse fill="#b2dfee" stroke="#b2dfee" cx="177.497" cy="-105" rx="47.3916" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="177.497" y="-101.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Campaign</text>
</g>
<!-- 3&#45;&gt;1 -->
<g id="edge3" class="edge"><title>3&#45;&gt;1</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#cd0000" d="M177.497,-76.7339C177.497,-63.4194 177.497,-47.806 177.497,-36.1754"/>
<polygon fill="#cd0000" stroke="#cd0000" points="173.997,-76.7989 177.497,-86.799 180.997,-76.799 173.997,-76.7989"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="198.997" y="-57.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00"> Parent </text>
</g>
<!-- 4 -->
<g id="node5" class="node"><title>4</title>
<ellipse fill="#b2dfee" stroke="#b2dfee" cx="271.497" cy="-105" rx="28.6953" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="271.497" y="-101.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Lead</text>
</g>
<!-- 4&#45;&gt;1 -->
<g id="edge4" class="edge"><title>4&#45;&gt;1</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#cd0000" d="M251.874,-81.4584C243.735,-72.5603 233.988,-62.4628 224.497,-54 216.904,-47.2291 208.071,-40.4074 200.126,-34.6078"/>
<polygon fill="#cd0000" stroke="#cd0000" points="249.277,-83.8042 258.567,-88.8979 254.481,-79.1226 249.277,-83.8042"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="259.997" y="-57.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00"> Parent </text>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: hey...thanks...but if number is bigger it is not fitting in circle

Comment: This code is working fine for label length up to 3 digits. When does it breaks? I don't see your chart labels with length greater than 3.

Comment: yah,right now data is not having number gretaer than 3 digit..but if number is like 20000,it wont fit the circle

Comment: You will have to increase the circle radius accordingly in that case. Will updated in answer.

Comment: hey,actually font of the text should be decreased,because i want to keep the circle radius constant

Comment: Okay.. You didn't mention that in your question. Do it that way then.